# Windows and Linux on different HDD and no grub, possible?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have a notebook with one SSD and one mSATA. I'd like to install Windows 10 LTSB N in the SSD and Ubuntu 16.04 in the mSATA.

Can I have those two installed without Grub 2? I mean, I only want to deal with the BIOS boot order, so I would have `Windows Boot Loader` and `ubuntu`, I'd set Windows to be 1st choice, so when I need linux, I would turn on the computer holding F12 to get the boot order, and from there select `ubuntu` to run.

The BIOS has settings regarding Windows Fast Start, Secure Boot, UEFI Boot, Legacy Boot, and I can enable/disable them if needed.

Is it possible? If positive, what should I do? Thanks.

---

IT'S WORKING, thanks @Android Dev and @John Orion!

I removed the mSATA and installed Windows in the SSD normally. Then I removed the SSD and put the mSATA again and installed Ubuntu normally.

Now my UEFI BOOT order is like that:

- Entry 01: Windows Boot Manager
- Entry 02: ubuntu
- Entry 03: Ubuntu

I'll later check why I have two entries for Ubuntu, as they both point to the same thing. I hope when I update Windows and/or Ubuntu they don't mess with this!

Comment: It may work if you removed one drive so you only have one drive in the computer ... then install one  OS ... then remove that drive and put in the other drive so there is only one drive in the computer and install the other OS .. then each OS should be independent of each other ... if you ever do an `update-grub` it would probably add the Windows menu item but I still believe it wouldn't change the grub location or anything.. if you choose to try this and it works please let me know and I will add this as an answer so it may help others

Comment: Thanks, it seems @Android Dev said the same thing. I'll try this ASAP.

Comment: But best to install both systems in same boot mode, both UEFI or both BIOS. And when you disconnect an UEFI drive it loses its entry in NVRAM and may need that reset by either rebooting a couple of times or using efibootmgr to add entry.

Comment: @oldfred that's what I'm doing, both UEFI. I never wanted to install them in different boot modes. I was just saying that I have the option to change that, because some systems don't have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is no.

**However, it is possible to achieve your end goal** by installing Ubuntu (and thus GRUB) to the mSATA without the other drive connected.

Next, install Windows to the other drive **without** the mSATA disconnected.

Then connect both, and set the other drive before the mSATA in the boot order.

Comment: lol beat me by a minute @Android Dev

Comment: @JohnOrion - Actually, I was typing this as your comment appeared :)

Comment: It worked, see question for updates!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need to disconnect the drives. Install Windows first, then install Ubuntu. During the installation choose to install grub onto the msata instead the ssd, which would be default. (Probably '/dev/sdb')

Comment: I've already tried that way, but it doesn't work as Ubuntu always take in consideration the Windows installed in the SSD.

Comment: But if you install grub on the msata instead the ssd, you'll only see grub if booting from there. You can run 'grub-install /dev/sdb' (check for your correct device name) and reinstall the windows boot loader. (not sure how, maybe from a recovery dvd). If you don't like that Windows is also available in grub, remove '/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober' and run 'update-grub'.